# xmlDom Call to a member function item() on a non object

Tags: php, html, xmldom

Hi I have a table with rows and columns.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-size:14px"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td background="image.jpg"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And im using this code to get all the elements with tag name `td`

```
$td= $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('td');
```

Then looping it to get each `td` tag through this code

```
for($i = 0; $i<$td->length; $x++){
   print_r($td->item($i));
}
```

The problem is when there is a `style` attribute inside the `td` tag, i'm getting this error
`Fatal error: Call to a member function item() on a non-object`. But if i remove the `style` attribute inside the `td` tag it works.

So this one works:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td background="image.jpg"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And this one doesn't

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-size:14px;"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td background="image.jpg"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My goal is to access the `background` attribute inside the `td` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `foreach` to make life more easier

```
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('td') as $tag) {
    if ($tag->getAttribute('background')) {
        echo $tag->getAttribute('background'); //"prints" image.jpg
    }
}
```

[<kbd>Working Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/135727)

Comment: Thanks done with the revision and this made my function easier, and now works properly thank you!

Comment: Glad to be of help mate